# "In auction" or "for auction"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> The house is to be sold **in/for** auction.

Which preposition is appropriate?

Is it *in* or *for*?

why?

Comment: This graph may demonstration what phase is more commonly used nowadays and in the past: https://goo.gl/eEkwGT.

Comment: but what happens when those prepositions are applied in the OP's example sentence? :) Which would be correct?

Comment: @Usernew - I would call "in auction" incorrect.  The house is *for sale at auction* or *up for auction* are the standard phrases.

Comment: Thanks @stangdon but have a look at my answer, the last example from Wiki.

Comment: @Usernew - Yes, but that's a different usage.  *The house was sold in the auction* is not the same thing as *The house is in auction*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The more common preposition to use would be "at," and "by," and "in."

If you are using the word "[auction](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/auction)" as a verb:

> The house is to be sold by auction.

else:

> The house is to be sold **at** (an) auction.
>   The house was sold **in** the auction.
>   This is a list of the most expensive cars sold **in** auto auctions.<sup>1</sup>

**For** would be wrong in your context.

> The house is to be sold for auction.

can mean that the house is being sold to fund an auction.

Have a look at the Ngram:
[image]

### [image]

<sub>1.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_expensive_cars_sold_in_auction)</sub>

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid *none!*

More common use is 'at'

> The house is to be sold ***at*** auction.

---

More natural IMO would be..

> The house is put up for auction

Comment: "Put up for auction" is fine, but "at auction" (without any article) sounds wrong to me.

Comment: I first thought of it but I again thought that the article rule for a noun does not depend on the clause it follows. Would you mind explaining why the former is fine and the latter isn't? @200_success

Comment: You can put the article an or leave it out as the word auction is used either as a countable or uncountable noun.